# Linux shared memory queue

Tags: c++, linux, posix, shared-memory

Is it possible to place

```
struct Data
{
   std::queue<int> mydata;
}
```

in linux shared memory and perform queue operations from different programs? any alternative methods other than custom implementation of queue using array?

I have below sample testapp for send and recive.

```
//sender.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <deque>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

struct SharedData
{
    std::deque<int> queue;
};

int main()
{
    const char *sharedMemoryName = "/my_shared_memory";
    // Create shared memory
    int sharedMemoryFd = shm_open(sharedMemoryName, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (sharedMemoryFd == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create shared memory" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "create shared memory success" << std::endl;
    }
    // Set the size of shared memory
    size_t sharedMemorySize = sizeof(SharedData);
    if (ftruncate(sharedMemoryFd, sharedMemorySize) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to set shared memory size" << std::endl;
        shm_unlink(sharedMemoryName);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "success to set shared memory size" << std::endl;
    }
    // Map the shared memory into the process address space
    void *sharedMemoryPtr = mmap(NULL, sharedMemorySize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sharedMemoryFd, 0);
    if (sharedMemoryPtr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to map shared memory" << std::endl;
        shm_unlink(sharedMemoryName);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "success to map shared memory" << std::endl;
    }
    // Construct the deque in shared memory
    SharedData *sharedData = new (sharedMemoryPtr) SharedData;
    // Producer process

    // Access the shared deque
    std::deque<int> &sharedQueue = sharedData->queue;
    // Produce some data
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // Acquire lock or use appropriate synchronization mechanism
        // Add data to the shared deque
        sharedQueue.push_back(i);
        std::cout << "Added data : " << i << std::endl;
        // Release lock or synchronization mechanism
        sleep(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

    // Wait for child processes to complete
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    cv.wait(lock);
    // Cleanup
    munmap(sharedMemoryPtr, sharedMemorySize);
    shm_unlink(sharedMemoryName);
    return 0;
}
```

Receiver code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <deque>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

struct SharedData
{
    std::deque<int> queue;
};

int main()
{
    const char *sharedMemoryName = "/my_shared_memory";
    // Create shared memory
    int sharedMemoryFd = shm_open(sharedMemoryName, O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (sharedMemoryFd == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create shared memory" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "success to create shared memory" << std::endl;
    }
    // Set the size of shared memory
    size_t sharedMemorySize = sizeof(SharedData);
    if (ftruncate(sharedMemoryFd, sharedMemorySize) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to set shared memory size" << std::endl;
        shm_unlink(sharedMemoryName);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "success to set shared memory size" << std::endl;
    }
    // Map the shared memory into the process address space
    void *sharedMemoryPtr = mmap(NULL, sharedMemorySize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sharedMemoryFd, 0);
    if (sharedMemoryPtr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to map shared memory" << std::endl;
        shm_unlink(sharedMemoryName);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "success to map shared memory" << std::endl;
    }
    // Construct the deque in shared memory
    SharedData *sharedData = new (sharedMemoryPtr) SharedData;

    // Consumer process

    // Access the shared deque
    std::deque<int> &sharedQueue = sharedData->queue;
    // Consume data
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // Acquire lock or use appropriate synchronization mechanism
        // Check if the deque is not empty
        std::cout<<"Is empty : "<<sharedQueue.empty()<<std::endl;
        if (!sharedQueue.empty())
        {
            // Process the front element
            int data = sharedQueue.front();
            sharedQueue.pop_front();
            std::cout << "Data recived  : " << data << std::endl;
        }
        // Release lock or synchronization mechanism
        sleep(1);
    }

    // Wait for child processes to complete
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    cv.wait(lock);

    return 0;
}
```

In above code receiver shows queue is empty always. can you help ?

Comment: Everything is possible. It's merely a question of understanding how things work, and how to make them work. In this case: 1) all processes must attach the shared memory segment at the same virtual address 2) a custom allocator must be written to allocate memory for the container from the share memory segment 3) placement new must be used to instantiate the container itself in the shared memory segment 4) proper synchronization must be implemented, using either file locks, or kernel-provided futexes, or something else. Are you familiar with all of these highly advanced, technical, C++ topics?

Comment: It would be significantly easier to use **Redis** which would also give you scalability across networks and interoperability with Python, Rust, bash, Java, PHP.

Comment: Can you help with the above code?

Comment: Above code is beyond help naive. Maybe look into source code of boost.interprocess <https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/interprocess.html> to see how such classes can be built in C++.